# Same path and same number of parameters but different components for routing in Angular 5 application

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AComponent },
    ...
    { path: 'homes/:id/:rate/:item', component: HomesComponent},
    { path: 'details/:id/:name/:product', component: DetailComponent},
    ...
]
```

As per client's requirement, we need to change the path to homes for both components. So we've updated the app.routing.module.ts.

**Updated app.routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AComponent },
    ...
    { path: 'homes/:id/:rate/:item', component: HomesComponent},
    { path: 'homes/:id/:name/:product', component: DetailComponent},
    ...
]
```

but, due to the **same number of parameters that we're using in each component** we are getting conflict and it's not rendering properly, for all condition it is routing to HomesComponent that we've given first in the Routes list.

Do you guys have any suggestions to resolve this issue, without compromising the path and number of parameters?

Comment: interesting question, i don't know how to do this, but you can play around by adding constant word on your url pattern like this : `{ path: 'homes/:id/:rate/item/:item', component: HomesComponent}` ?

Comment: How would YOU differentiate between `HomeComponent` and 'DetailComponent` paths?

Comment: That doesn’t make much sense since a parameter can be anything how would the router know the difference? The way router works out the paths is with paths, not parameters. Why don’t you include an additional element on your path like homes/detail/...?

Comment: @Yanis-git Hugo Noro adding constant word is not possible because the client needed same URL structure as it is which is already indexed in Google.

Comment: @ritaj Yeah, that's what we're trying to figure out.

Comment: @AlwinRichard Does `rate` and `name` are same data types?

Answer (score 10):

Use custom `UrlMatcher` when `paths` and `parameters` are not helpful

> Form official doc:
>    A custom [URL matcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) can be provided when a combination of path and 
>    pathMatch isn't expressive enough

In your case i would create a custom matcher.

**SOLUTION 1:**

```
export const routes = [{ 
  matcher: homeCustomerMatcher,
  component: HomeComponent 
}, {
  matcher: detailsCustomerMatcher,
  component: DetailsComponent
}];
```

***Scenario A: If the data types are different for parameters. Assuming`/:rate` params is number data type and `/:name` is string***

```
export function homeCustomerMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]){
 return url.length === 3 && isInteger(url[1].path * 1) ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
}
```

***Scenario B: If the `/:name` values are pre defined. Assuming`:/rate and :/name` is same date type***

In this case we can create a collection/array of possible name values and compare the values again the path values.

```
const possibleNameValues = ["A","B","C"];
export function homeCustomerMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]){
 return url.length === 3 &&  possibleNameValues.includes(url[1].path)  
 ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
}
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

Using `regex`with `UrlMatcher` to match the param data type

```
  {
    path: 'homes/:id',
    children: [
        {
            path: ':rate',
            matcher: NumericUrlMatcher,
            component: Ratecomponent
        },
        {
            path: ':name',
            component: NameComponent
        }
   }
```

Now you customer matcher function should be updated to

```
 export function NumericUrlMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]) {
    const regex = new RegExp(...);
    const match = url[0].path.match(regex);
    return match !== null && match[0].length === url[0].path.length;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try your approach and update. :)

Comment: @Karthick: Great one :)

Answer (score 4):

You could make a wrapper component with `the path` and programatically `route` to different components.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AComponent },
    ...
    { path: 'homes/:id/:rate/:item', component: WrapperComponent},
    ...
]
```

Wrapper template:

```
<detail-component *ngIf="yourCondition"><detail-component>
<home-component *ngIf="!yourCondition"></home-component>
```

How would you go about finding the first method for `yourCondition` I don't know.

However, I would definitely advise against this.

Comment: very smart idea, i think is only way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

When for scenario like above, depends upon query parameter and not as route param, i find @ritaj's answer useful with few more lines of code to check for the routes like below. As UrlMatcher does not seem to have access to activated route and thus the params with it.

Route

```
{ path: 'apply', component: ApplicationRouterComponent },
```

Route handler component

```
export class ApplicationRouterComponent implements OnInit {

  type: string;
  state: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(q => {
      this.type = q['type'];
      this.state = q['state'];
    });
  }

  showApplicationForm(): boolean {
    return this.type !== 'new' || this.state !== 'inprogress';
  }

  showInProgressForm(): boolean {
    return this.type === 'new' && this.state === 'inprogress';
  }

}
```

Route handler html

```
<app-application *ngIf="showApplicationForm()"></app-application>
<app-resume *ngIf="showInProgressForm()"></app-resume>
```