# Angular 9 same route paths different components

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-route-guards

I'm trying to resolve the correct path of a set of URLs that share the same structure. I have the path `/:id/:areaId` and `/:id/:cityId` and this is done by design for SEO reasons. When I come to implement it I need to know if `:areaId` exists (by making an API call) and if it doesn't then I will try to check if `:cityId` exists to navigate to it.

The first thing I thought of was the `canActivate` in my route because I need to inject a service and it seemed natural to me. I implemented the guard and applied to the `area` component and my trouble here is when the `canActivate` is `false` because the navigation stops. I've been reading about using urlMatchers however I don't think I have all information needed in the segments and injecting services using something like [Angular 2 different components with same route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928727/angular-2-different-components-with-same-route) seems wrong to me and also it does fail if I try to navigate directly to the URL as opposed to navigating via home - the injector is not defined when I do navigate directly.

My question is, using guards or something similiar, can I "navigate to the next matching URL" when the result of my guard is false?

For reference, my guard looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AreaGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private areasService: AreasService) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const areaId= route.params['areaId'];
        return this.areasService.isArea(areaId)
                                .then(a => {
                                    return true;
                                })
                                .catch(e => {
                                    console.log('Checking area', e);
                                    return false;
                                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768534/same-path-and-same-number-of-parameters-but-different-components-for-routing-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would create an `Component` to handle this specification.
Doing HTTP calls inside `Guards` it is something I would not recommend.

You could have only one route and load your new created component.
Do your HTTP calls and then with a simple `*ngIf` you could decide what component
to load.