# Angular 13 - Lazy load multiple components matching the same URL structure

Tags: angular, angular-lazyloading

I'm creating an `Angular 13` app that has multiple components that can match the same URL although they would render different content (as in different components) based on the URL value. Thus I can have, like I do in [Angular 9 same route paths different components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63522311/angular-9-same-route-paths-different-components) 's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63522451/5293466 I create like a "selector" component that performs the logic and then decides which component should be viewed. That's all fine however this approach - as far as I know - can't handle lazy loading.

***I would like to know if I am able to call a component within a component and lazy load the module of it*** . Is that something achievable? Otherwise how would you handle the scenario where you can have many routes such as `/:id/:cityId` , `/:id/:townId` , `/:id/:regionId` , `/:id/:countryId` , etc, etc where you can have a growing list of possibilities and avoid getting a bigger bundle for that particular module? Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, you are able to lazy load components via the ComponentFactory. Please take a look at this blog for an in-depth understanding.
[https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/lazy-load-components-in-angular-596357ab05d8](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/lazy-load-components-in-angular-596357ab05d8)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, thanks to the comments I was able to play around with the code from the article: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/lazy-load-components-in-angular-596357ab05d8 and https://github.com/wittyprogramming/lazy-load-component-angular13 to get it to work. I actually instantiate the relevant component I need, based on a certain condition, using the example here: https://github.com/wittyprogramming/lazy-load-component-angular13/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts#L31 and violà, I can get the different chunks loaded as I need